# Having trouble with Tryton/GNU Health installation

Tags: python, postgresql, tryton

I have installed Tryton server and client as instructed on the GNU Health website. The server is running fine. The pre-requisites required - Postgresql, Python had been installed before hand. I have created a GNU Health user but whenever I attempt creating a database in postgres, i get the error shown in the terminal below - 
[image]

This is my pg_hba.conf file, with the configuration as specified in the installation instruction - [image]

Also, this is my trytond.conf file - 
[image]

Please, can someone point out what i'm doing wrong because each time i run the Tryton client, it doesn't see any server and I an only run the demo profile. Also if I try creating a database from the Tryton client, It keeps giving me an error can't create database.

I have tried several edits to the conf file with no avail.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you have to specify a username and password to let PostgreSQL trust your connection. Also take care that you are allowing anyone to conect to your server with any login. This may be a security issue.

Using the following URI works for me:

> postgresql://username:sometext@localhost:5432